# How can I localise iOS system pop-up (such as Delete photo system pop-up, not photo permission pop-up)?

Tags: ios, iphone

In my app; delete photo system pop-up is not localising properly. It does not localising system pop-up such as Delete photo system pop-up. I am not talking about localising any permission pop-up.

Comment: As it's a system alert it probably just uses the device language and cannot be localised (as this would allow you to potentially show a different/irrelevant message to the user).

Comment: pop-up language does not change when I change device language, it is the problem.

Comment: I think it is a system bug in iOS. Photo Cleaner app also have this problem. Photo Cleaner's Delete photo system pop-up does not translate when device language changes.